# Why <script> and <iframe> tag is not working in the source page of iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I am developing an online HTML editor. For this, I have used a form element. Inside the form, there is a Textarea which will contain HTML codes and an Iframe which will render the HTML code. The target of the form is the Iframe.

This is my code in the editor:

```
<form id="edfrm" method="post" action="/source.php" target="frame"> 
<textarea name="code" id="code"></textarea> 
<iframe allowtransparency="false" src="/source.php" name="frame" id="frame"></iframe> 
<button id="subbutton">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

When the form is submitted the value of the Textarea goes to source.php, the Iframe collects source code from source.php and renders result.

Here is the source.php:

```
<?php
$runCode = @$_REQUEST["code"];
print $runCode ;
?>
```

But when I write HTML codes with 'script' tag or 'iframe' tag in the Textarea and submit the form, my project does not work. The error says, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)". When I remove the 'script' or 'iframe' tag it works fine.

Please help me if I am facing a server problem, PHP configuration problem or other. SVG also works, but what is the problem for 'script' and 'iframe'?

**I think, IT'S A VERY SERIOUS PROBLEM FOR ME AND OTHERS LIKE ME. PLEASE HELP!**

***Example: I am writing this code in the textarea.***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id = "canvas1" width = "200" height = "100" style = "border-style:solid;  border-width:1px;">
</canvas>
<script>
var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100,50,40,0,2*Math.PI,true);
ctx.strokeStyle = "Green";
ctx.lineWidth = "10";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "Yellow"
ctx.fill();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is not working and giving error. When I remove the script tag, the code runs.

Comment: What is the url of your page that contains your Iframe and the url of your Iframe?

Comment: The page which contain the iframe is editor.php

Comment: The server is giving the browser a forbidden error. Read the server logs to find out what triggered that. You probably have an anti-XSS filter in place that just rejects anything that looks like it could be an attack from user input.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly:

1. U post your content to source.php.
2. The result code contains an iframe with an attribute

   > **src="source.php"**
3. So your page and your iframe both takes source from source.php.

That causes a loop so that is normal that u take 403. Please change your iframe's src attribute to anything else and try again.

Comment: No. The problem is not there. The error is only when I add a <script> or <iframe> tag in the Textarea. When I omit the <script> or <iframe> tag it works fine.

Comment: can u send an example of posted data in your request and the text result of your request? eg print <xmp>$runCode</xmp> ;

Comment: and the result of <xmp>$runCode</xmp> ?

Comment: The form has a target attribute. It doesn't load recursively.

Comment: What to do? Please help me. @Quentin

Comment: @hmc — As I said in a comment on the question: **read the server logs**

Comment: @Quentin he said that he **posted** his data to **source.php**, and the example he gave has **iframe** allowtransparency="false" **src="/source.php"**